# C# with selenium doesn't recognize element

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing a test case for login and logout for an app.
When I get to the login form, it doesn't find elements saying there is no such element (email and password).

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;



namespace exchange_drop_test_login
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://exchangedrop.com");

            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='/Account/Login']")).Click();



            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='yours@example.com']")).GetAttribute("placeholder");


        }
    }
}
```

It crashes on last line. Could someone tell me how to find elements "email" and "password"?

I tried finding by class name, xpath, name, but nothing works.

html for email object:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value="">
```

Comment: And we need to guess how those elements look like...

Comment: You can inspect it.

Comment: can you please provide your html code for more clarification of your issue. We are unable to give you solution without looking at html code for email, password fields in your html DOM.

Comment: Whats the Page your inspecting like, I'd have thought it would be easiest simply to find by id, also there don't seem to be any username/ password fields on the page your viewing..

Comment: look at this page: https://airdrop.eu.auth0.com/login?state=oqB-pMs-YoHXVcLee3J04Q8E_d-0nV7M&client=Opu7qNSDpQeYVQ7NZmqtw6zXmXizJDix&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexchangedrop.com%2Fsignin-auth0&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&nonce=636748435678965410.ODE1N2QxYjctNmI5OS00NGYyLTk5MmItMmE5MWQxMDg1YjQyN2RkNjM1NzctOGNmOS00MzgzLWFkOGQtYTIyYzkzODg4NjZl&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.1.0

Comment: this is the login page, after you click on (4th line of code)

Comment: Why are you getting the attribute `placeholder` when you just used it in a locator? You already know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

when we executing after clicking new tab gets opened. 
But selenium driver keep on working on old tab.
So that driver is unable to find locate elements like email and password.

new tab gets opened at url https://airdrop.eu.auth0.com and you are doing your operations on last opened window.You have to switch between windows.So, driver.SwitchTo().Window() will help you in that.

this will surely help you i tested it worked for me,

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://exchangedrop.com");

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='/Account/Login']")).Click();

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> str = driver.WindowHandles;

driver.SwitchTo().Window(str.ToArray<string>()[1]);

driver.FindElement(By.Name("email")).SendKeys("    "); 
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("    ");
string data = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='yours@example.com']")).GetAttribute("placeholder");
Console.writeLine(data); // Your data will get printed on console
```

Comment: you are looking at the wrong page:https://airdrop.eu.auth0.com/login?state=oqB-pMs-YoHXVcLee3J04Q8E_d-0nV7M&client=Opu7qNSDpQeYVQ7NZmqtw6zXmXizJDix&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexchangedrop.com%2Fsignin-auth0&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&nonce=636748435678965410.ODE1N2QxYjctNmI5OS00NGYyLTk5MmItMmE5MWQxMDg1YjQyN2RkNjM1NzctOGNmOS00MzgzLWFkOGQtYTIyYzkzODg4NjZl&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.1.0